# Call to a member function send() on a non-object

Tags: php, cakephp

My cakePHP version 2.2.3

I am getting error message while i am sending email to someone.

Code:

```
                $to = 'xxxxxxxx@xxxxxx.xx';
                $from='noreply@xxxx.xx';
                $sendMessage ='hello world!';
                $Email = new CakeEmail();
                $Email->template('default')
                    ->emailFormat('html')
                    ->to($to)
                    ->from($from)                   
                    ->subject('My Subject')
                    ->send($sendMessage);
```

Error Message-

**Fatal error**:  Call to a member function send() on a non-object in **/home/chatfun/app/Model/User.php** on line **78**

Where is problem of my code?

Comment: `subject()` isn't returning an object.  check the return type.

Comment: Can you please say, in your own words, what the error message says? I am just curious to know why people are unable to understand it.

Answer (score 4):

From the source extract :

```
 556:     public function subject($subject = null) {
 557:         if ($subject === null) {
 558:             return $this->_subject;
 559:         }
 560:         $this->_subject = $this->_encode((string)$subject);
 561:         return $this;
 562:     }
```

As u see when u provide `null`as subject it will return the subject and not the instance.
So be sure that your `$getSetting['Setting']['subject']`is not null. What is the case at this moment

[source](http://api.cakephp.org/2.1/source-class-CakeEmail.html#550-562)

Comment: According the the code listed, they are providing a subject to the function, which would negate this as being the cause, since the local function `$subject` is what is checked to return it rather than the instance.

Comment: OP updated question. Original question stated passing a var to the subject

Comment: @Jon The question was edited a few times, maybe it was using a variable in its original version? edit: DarkBee beet me to it :)

Comment: This answer is correct. Seems like the above example in the question is not what the actual code looks like :)

Comment: Haha, I had checked version history, and they all showed the subject having a value, but I guess those first 5min of not showing the edit beat me to it. lol

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend calling the setter methods themselves. Mainly because if you're planning to write a test case for this it will make your life a lot easier;

**Model**

```
// /Model/User.php

function sendEmail() {
    if (!$this->Email) {
        $this->Email = new CakeEmail();
    }
    $this->Email->to('xxxxxxxx@xxxxxx.xx');
    $this->Email->from('noreply@xxxx.xx');
    $this->Email->emailFormat('html');
    $this->Email->template('default');
    $this->Email->subject('My Subject');
    $this->Email->send();
}
```

**Test**

```
// /Test/Case/Model/UserTest.php

function testSendEmail() {

    $this->User->Email = $this->getMock('CakeEmail');

    $this->User->Email->expects($this->once())
        ->method('to')
        ->with($this->equalTo('xxxxxxxx@xxxxxx.xx'));

    $this->User->Email->expects($this->once())
        ->method('subject')
        ->with($this->equalTo('My subject'));

    $this->User->Email->expects($this->once())
        ->method('send');

    $this->User->sendEmail();
}
```